# Automatically add activity when sending bulk email

Tags: civimail, activities

I noticed that one of my predecessors added an activity to each user whenever they were sent a bulk email. However, when I send a bulk email it does not create an activity. Is this something that can be done automatically?

Answer (score 3):

There’s an option in the CiviMail Component Settings.

Administer > CiviMail > CiviMail Component Settings

Make sure the option ‘Enable CiviMail to create activities on delivery’ is checked.

This will then automatically create a ‘Bulk Email’ activity for each recipient.

Comment: So that box is already checked but isn't working - I tried unchecking, saving and re-checking to see if that will help

Comment: Does the activity type ‘Bulk Email’ exist in your environment?
Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Activity Types

Comment: Yes it does exist